# Cannot make JAR/WAR executable work with embedded Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, jar, tomcat7, pom.xml

I have a maven project using the `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. I am trying to package the project into a jar (or war) so it can be run without using maven (`mvn tomcat7:run`). My attempts so far have not resulted in displaying the webpage correctly.

I have followed the steps in https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven (2.6: Web Application with Executable Tomcat). Additionally, the video tutorial on https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/video/Create-a-Java-executable-JAR-with-the-Tomcat-plug-in-for-Maven was followed. Several variants of these have been tried, altering the pom.xml parameters. A sample of the pom.xml is [here](https://pastebin.com/Q6CQa0U0).

Each time, the archive is built using the command `mvn clean install tomcat7:exec-war-only` and subsequently a .jar or .war archive is created in the target directory.

After creation, the achieve is run by `java -jar Application.jar`. The following output is observed:

```
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 29, 2019 9:58:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 29, 2019 9:58:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 29, 2019 9:58:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

When navigating to any address, such as http://localhost:8080/Application/home I receive a 404 error page (not served by Tomcat, but Chrome's error page). When running the same application through `mvn tomcat7:run` the page would load as expected.

Can anyone advise on this please?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the packaging (`.jar` or `.war`), your web page resources (html/css/js files) have to be on different location. And I guess your URI call an index.html page?

- For `.jar` packaging put it in `src/main/resources` folder
- For `.war` packaging put it in `src/main/webapp` folder

In your case, your URL is not reachable and I suspect your web resources are not in the good folder.

This [link](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-exploded-war.html) can help you understand more clearly

Comment: Hi Harry, thanks for the response. I have tried to follow the layout you suggested but still no luck. My solution ideally needs to be without the use of Spring Boot. Would you be able to assist further?

Comment: What is the type of project you are working on Java EE, SE?

Comment: The project is Java SE, running version 1.8 of the SDK. `javax.servlet-api` included as a dependency and also the `tomcat7-maven-plugin`.

Comment: I have also included a sample of my pom.xml, viewable at https://pastebin.com/Q6CQa0U0

Comment: I don't really know but, as you are using an embedded `tomcat` server you have to share a web resource or implement in your code a HttpServlet interface that will responde to your request. You can also use `Jetty` if you want an embedded web server. At least it seems like your packaging works, but the ressources you are sharing are not available. Can you share your code ?